# How to write to a file in Android?

Tags: java, android, io

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create a file in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239026/how-to-create-a-file-in-android)

I have a game that requires the user to "login". Instead of having to type in their username and password everytime, i would there to be a auto-login feature. So when the user starts up the app all they have to do is press a login button and it will log them in automatically so that they dont have to input their username and password everytime. I thought i could write a file containing the username and password and then the app could read from that file and then send that information to the server. How do i create a file in android? How do then write to that file? How do i read from it? I can do I/O stuff in Java so I know the basics but i dont think it is the same for android. Can someone walk me through it?

Comment: A (very) quick Google search yielded [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For something this simple, try a [SharedPreference](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref).  Other options can be found here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Answer (score 0):

I agree with ImR, it is probably better to use SharedPreferences. But if you want to use a file it is very similar to Java, take a look at this [page](http://www.anddev.org/working_with_files-t115.html) for a sample.