# How to include a static log file into an Android app that won't be removed on closing the app?

Tags: java, android, file, stream, logging

I want to include a static log file within my app. Whenever the user starts the app, a time with extra information will be appended to that file. At the beginning, I thought storing the file into assets folder or raw folder would be the solution, but then I looked into [android documentations](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal) where it states:

> Tip: If you want to save a static file in your application at compile
> time, save the file in your project res/raw/ directory. You can open
> it with openRawResource(), passing the R.raw. resource ID.
> This method returns an InputStream that you can use to read the file
> (**but you cannot write to the original file**).

How can I solve this problem?

**EDIT:**

I want the log file not to be removed on closing the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
private void writeLog(String s)
{
    String FILENAME = "log.txt";
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try
    {
        fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_APPEND);
        fos.write(s.getBytes());
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e){}
    catch(IOException e){}
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            fos.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e){}
    }
}
```

```
private void readLog(EditText logs)
{
    String FILENAME = "log.txt";
    FileInputStream in = null;
    try
    {
        in = openFileInput(FILENAME);
    }
    catch(IOException e1){}
    try
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096]; // Read 4K characters at a time.
        int len;
        logs.setText("");
        while((len = in.read(buffer)) != -1)
        {
            String s = new String(buffer, 0, len);
            logs.append(s);
        }
    }
    catch(IOException e){}
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            if(in != null) in.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e){}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of including the log file with the app you should create it on first launch.

There's more information [How to create a file in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239026/how-to-create-a-file-in-android) on creating a file.

Comment: I know how to create a file, but where should I store it?

Answer (score 0):

Well i don't see the problem, your user will open the app and it will be **runtime** and you can write what ever you want to what ever file. So this tip doesn't apply to you.

Comment: But when the user closes the app and run it again, the log file will be empty.