# File path in Java on Android

Tags: java, android, file

When I upload my program to my Android device, it will have a text file on the device. I have created it in the package directory, and I suppose that it will be uploaded to the device when I deploy the package.

How can I find the file path of the text file in order to be able to use it from the application, so I can read from the file?

I tried some simple code: `File file=new File("test.txt");`

Is this possible and if so, how can it be done?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8001067/how-to-include-a-static-log-file-into-an-android-app-that-wont-be-removed-on-cl

Comment: it will have a text file on the device and you have created it in the package directory? means where you want to put this text file exactly, in assets directory or in sdcard?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Import your test.txt file in the directory

```
/mnt/sdcard/
```

and access it

```
String youFilePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/test.txt"
File file=new File(youFilePath);
```

Hope this will work in your case...

Comment: if i create the file with eclipse in the package directory and install the application to the device how i will be able to access the file, if this is possible?