# How to know if the App is being replaced with another version (Not upgrade)

Tags: java, android

Suppose I have APK the I installed it, then I modified something in this APK and replace (re-install) it (without changing version)? I want to get that replace event. Is that even possible?

Because I'm using SharedPreferences in order to do something only at first time launch of the application, now if I replace the App this SharedPreferences is not reseted (I need to con side replacing the App as first time launch). Any ideas?

Comment: Build.VERSION_CODES also Build class may be helpful

Comment: if you change things in your apk, you should probably change the version code. that's what it is for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could store some sort of flag or even the preferences themselves in the data/ directory on the user's device.

Then, when you start the app, if this data exists you know that the app has been there before regardless of version.

Comment: How to store and read, and with what format? please if you can provide code it will be helpful, didn't try to store in data directory before.

Comment: you can just use a text file.  This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239026/how-to-create-a-file-in-android

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there's any event which is broadcasted without changing the version value. However, it is recommended to change `android:versionCode` in order to detect version differences for a package.