# Application to write data to a file

Tags: android, file

I'm writing a android app that writes the accelerometer values to a file, I'm getting the values to show up on the screen but I don't know if it is writing them to a file, and if it is I can't find the file.

I have this method, but I'm not sure if it is doing it right;

```
public void WriteToFile()
{
    try
    {
        final String accelValue = new String(accelXValue + "," + accelYValue + "," + accelZValue);
        FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput("accelValue.txt", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut); 
        // Write the string to the file
        osw.write(accelValue);

        osw.flush();
        osw.close();
    }
    finally
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

Where would this store the file on a phone?

Should I call this somewhere in my code or is it OK that it follows the accelerometer methods?

Thanks.

Also, the app needs to create the file its writing to.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8738467/1383281

Would this answer help?

Here's the new code but it still doesn't seem to do anything.

```
public void WriteToFile() 
{ 
    File AccelData = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "AccelData.txt");
    try
    {
        if (!(AccelData.exists()))
                {
                    AccelData.createNewFile();
                }

        final String accelValue = new String(accelXValue + "," + accelYValue + "," + accelZValue);
        FileOutputStream ADOut = openFileOutput("accelValue.txt", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        OutputStreamWriter AD = new OutputStreamWriter(ADOut);
        AD.write(accelValue);
    }
    finally
    {
        return;
    } 
}
```

Comment: You should probably open the file once, write all the values you want, and then close it once. That code looks like it's meant to open the file and close it several times.

Comment: What would I need to change? The only thing I can think about is removing the `osw.close()`. I'd presume I also need some sort of loop around it so to keep it writing the values, and close when the app closes?

Answer (score 1):

```
public void WriteToFile()
{
    FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput("accelValue.txt", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);

    try
    {
        final String accelValue = new String(accelXValue + "," + accelYValue + "," + accelZValue);
        // Write the string to the file
        osw.write(accelValue);
    }
    finally
    {
        osw.flush();
        osw.close();
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

for different options to write to a file. You basically can write to

- Internal Storage - Store private data on the device memory.
- External Storage - Store public data on the shared external storage.

and must take care of permission etc.