# how to create .json file and how to write json object into json file ...In android

Tags: android

I am  using this code for creating the new file and write the json object in test.json file but I am unable to create file.Please find mistake and give the best result 
One things I have also write the code for  permission in manifest file..

Thanks,

```
String fileName = "test";
        File file = new File("/data/data/packagename/test.json");
        file.createNewFile();
            DataOutputStream fos = new  DataOutputStream(openFileOutput(fileName , Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
            if(file.exists()){
                fos.write(jsString.getBytes());
                fos.close();
            }
```

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239026/how-to-create-a-file-in-android?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

This will not land on C:/ anyway. At best at your SD card or some other folder, and since android is a unix based system. you should be careful on how you use "slashes"