# How to save cropped image in android instead of returning cropping data?

Tags: android, android-image

I have an application where I can let the user choose a gallery image or take a picture with camera, then after that I give him the option to crop it.

Now when the user crops the image the Gallery cropper returns ByteArray of the cropped part, is it possible to pass a parameter asking the Gallery cropper to save the output to file (Just like the case when I start a intent to capture and image in the camer)

e.g.:

This is the code of cropping that I Use:

```
// Initialize intent
Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
// set data type to be sent
intent.setType("image/*");

// get croppers available in the phone
List<ResolveInfo> list = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( intent, 0 );
int size = list.size();
// handle the case if there's no cropper in the phone
if (size == 0) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Can not find image crop app", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return;
} else {

// now this is the case if cropper exists
// initialize the Uri for the captures or gallery image

    Uri imageUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(mCurrentPhotoPath));

    // Send the Uri path to the cropper intent
    intent.setData(imageUri); 
    intent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
    intent.putExtra("outputY", 200);
    intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
    intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);         
    intent.putExtra("scale", true);
    // Here's my attempt to ask the intent to save output data as file
    File f = null;
    // Here I initialize empty file 
    try{
            // This returns the file created
        f = setUpCroppedFile();
        mCurrentThumbPath = f.getAbsolutePath();            
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));            
        intent.putExtra("output", Uri.fromFile(f));         
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------
    // -----------> When changing this to false it worked <----------------
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------        
    intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    // If there's only 1 Cropper in the phone (e.g. Gallery )
    if (size == 1) {
            // get the cropper intent found
            Intent i        = new Intent(intent);
            ResolveInfo res = list.get(0);

            i.setComponent( new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));

            startActivityForResult(i, CROPPED_PHOTO);
    }

   // Please ignore the case if there are more . . I know how to handle it
```

**Update: the issue is fixed, I see I'd leave this here as is in case someone else find it useful ( See the big comment inside the code above )**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code is the modified one and it works:

```
// Initialize intent
Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
// set data type to be sent
intent.setType("image/*");

// get croppers available in the phone
List<ResolveInfo> list = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( intent, 0 );
int size = list.size();
// handle the case if there's no cropper in the phone
if (size == 0) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Can not find image crop app", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return;
} else {

// now this is the case if cropper exists
// initialize the Uri for the captures or gallery image

    Uri imageUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(mCurrentPhotoPath));

    // Send the Uri path to the cropper intent
    intent.setData(imageUri); 
    intent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
    intent.putExtra("outputY", 200);
    intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
    intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);         
    intent.putExtra("scale", true);
    // Here's my attempt to ask the intent to save output data as file
    File f = null;
    // Here I initialize empty file 
    try{
            // This returns the file created
        f = setUpCroppedFile();
        mCurrentThumbPath = f.getAbsolutePath();            
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));            
        intent.putExtra("output", Uri.fromFile(f));         
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------
    // -----------> When changing this to false it worked <----------------
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------        
    intent.putExtra("return-data", false);
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    // If there's only 1 Cropper in the phone (e.g. Gallery )
    if (size == 1) {
            // get the cropper intent found
            Intent i        = new Intent(intent);
            ResolveInfo res = list.get(0);

            i.setComponent( new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));

            startActivityForResult(i, CROPPED_PHOTO);
    }

   // Please ignore the case if there are more . . I know how to handle it
```

Comment: #Shehbix @
error  where is setUpcroppedFile() method may i get its code cause am also facing same problem

Comment: @VikrantAlekar I'm sorry I no longer have this code, it was a transitional version of a project, but it's simply creating a file and returning a handle as far as I can remember, something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239026/how-to-create-a-file-in-android

Comment: its ok i got my solution n thnks for reply