# Load the cropped version of an image

Tags: android, imageview, crop

How can I save a cropped picture instead of the original? I want so save the cropped Version so I can load it (Form gallery or webserver) fitted into a imageview. But now if I crop the picture and set it into a imageview it works fine but after reloading the picture in the original size comes up. Do I need to save something like crop information for it?

Comment: Please provide some code snippets what you have tried

Comment: Here's the answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13337006/how-to-save-cropped-image-in-android-instead-of-returning-cropping-data

Comment: Thanks so far. After cropping the image it gets saved in my gallery. But the imageview I want to set the cropped image to turns white