# How to create a .txt file on a server using Android?

Tags: android, eclipse, file-upload

I have been given a task using an Android application whereby the user is presented with a "Contact Us" form on the device's screen and once they fill their name, subject and question, the program should create a file on my server in a particular folder and call the file something like *enquiry(date)(time)* for uniqueness.
I had a delve around and found some code that creates a file in /data/data/your_project_package_structure/files/samplefile.txt (link to post: 
[How to create a file in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239026/how-to-create-a-file-in-android)

So I was thinking: do I either use this code to create the file locally and then move the file to my server using something like `file.Rename` or do I create a custom solution (which I have no idea how to achieve)?

I would appreciate if anybody out there is capable of giving me some advice on this one and I hope other people find this helpful too.

Code samples will be mostly welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go 2 ways with this (probably more actually...)

I'll assume your server runs on PHP. Other server languages will not really change the options, just the execution.

1. You can create your file locally (seems you already figured out how to do that) and just upload that file to your server. You can google around for uploading to `$_FILES` which basically is a simple stream of bytes. 
   The server will just have to save the file somewhere.
2. Leave this work up to your server instead. Just send the info over in a post or get request, fetch the data with `$_GET` or `$_POST` and create a file & save on server. 
   This would probably be my personal choice, since you'll want to get any work a server can do, out of the hands of your much more limited mobile, saving resources such as data and battery usage.

Comment: thanks for your reply. You are correct my server supports PHP. Personally I would have gone with option 1 (mainly due to my inexperience with Android) however I believe, as you rightly pointed out, option 2 seems to be more efficient. Is there any chance you can provide me with some sample code/pseudocode for option 2? thanks for your reply one more time

Comment: You can simply use HttpGet or HttpPost in Android. There are already lots of tutorials on this, so im sure you can find it :). In PHP you can just use $_GET or $_POST as an array (per example $_GET['myVariable'] to extract the data. Do not know at the top of my head how to create a file, but again im sure Google will have a copy-paste answer.