# How can I write a file with an android app?

Tags: android, file

I writing a cryptographic app that will generate a public private key pair for RSA.  The private key needs to be saved on the device.  In testing with a normal java application, the keys were generated and then saved to file with the following:

```
public static void saveToFile(String fileName,BigInteger mod, BigInteger exp) throws IOException
   {
    ObjectOutputStream oout = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileName)));
        try
        {
                oout.writeObject(mod);
                oout.writeObject(exp);
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
                throw new IOException("Unexpected error", e);
        }

        finally
        {
                oout.close();
        }
}
```

The key file would appear in the project directory.  However, with the android app, this does not happen.  How can I write a file with an android app?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239026/how-to-create-a-file-in-android

Answer (score 2):

> The key file would appear in the project directory. However, with the android app, this does not happen. How can I write a file with an android app?

In Android, there are only two major places where your application can write files: it's private internal storage directory, and the external storage volume.  You have to do more than just provide a file name, you must provide the full path that includes on of these locations.

```
//Internal storage location using your filename parameter
File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), filename);

//External storage location using your filename parameter
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorage(), filename);
```

The difference being internal storage is only accessible by your app; external storage can be read/written from anywhere, including your PC if you connect and mount the storage over USB.

You can then wrap the appropriate file in the `FileOutputStream` of your existing code.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Perhaps I am totally missing something, but where do you get 'context'?  As it is, netbeans is telling me "cannot find symbol: variable context".  Sorry if this is a stupid question.  This is the first app I've ever tried building.

Comment: That was just to show that `getFilesDir()` is a method on `Context`, so you can call it on any `Context` object you have.  System components like `Activity` and `Service` all inherit from `Context`.

Comment: I guess I still don't understand.  I don't have any Context objects.  In fact, it is an abstract class and cannot be instantiated.

Comment: If you're running this code inside of an `Activity`, you can just use `getFilesDir()` directly.  If it's inside another class, you'll need to pass in a Context to the method (g.e., if it's **called from** an Activity, pass `this` to the method).  Otherwise, you need to use the external storage version that doesn't require one.

Comment: Ah!  Yes, I moved the meat of the method straight into MainActivity (which extends Activity) and then getFilesDir() worked by itself.  Now, I still cannot see the files I am trying to create, though.  I wonder if I am even able to?  Would they appear in the project directory or would they only exist in some netherworld within the emulator?

Comment: They're on the emulator/device.  If you want to pull them off, use DDMS/Monitor File Explorer to navigate to the `/data/data/<package_name>/files` directory of your emulator.  An Android application would have no way to create files on your host machine.

Answer (score 0):

First pass main class from you call as method:

```
Boolean writfile;
writfile =savTextFileInternal(this.getApplicationContext(),"Maa","Ambika");
Toast.makeText(this, "File write:"+writfile, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Create a method like this:

```
public boolean savTextFileInternal(Context context,String sFileName, String sBody)
{
    try
    {
        File root = new File(context.getFilesDir(),"myfolder");

        if (!root.exists()) {
            root.mkdirs();
        }

        File gpxfile = new File(root, sFileName);
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(gpxfile);
        writer.append(sBody);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        return  true;  
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```