# How to edit a file programmatically

Tags: android, file, android-activity

I want to do an app that can edit a file, like open a txt file, edit it, save and bearing in mind its permissions. How I can do this in a activity?

Thank you.

Comment: So, have you tried anything to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few days later I have the next methods.

```
private static byte[] readFromFile(String filePath, int position, int size)
        throws IOException {

    RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile(filePath, "r");
    file.seek(position);
    byte[] bytes = new byte[size];
    file.read(bytes);
    file.close();
    return bytes;

}

private void CopyFromAssetsToStorage(Context Context, String SourceFile, String DestinationFile) throws IOException {
    InputStream IS = Context.getAssets().open(SourceFile);
    OutputStream OS = new FileOutputStream(DestinationFile);
    CopyStream(IS, OS);
    OS.flush();
    OS.close();
    IS.close();
}

private void CopyStream(InputStream Input, OutputStream Output) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[5120];
    int length = Input.read(buffer);
    while (length > 0) {
        Output.write(buffer, 0, length);
        length = Input.read(buffer);
    }
}

private static void writeToFile(String filePath, String data, int position) throws IOException {

    RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile(filePath, "rw");
    file.seek(position);
    file.write(data.getBytes());
    file.close();



public static String readFileAsString(String filePath) throws IOException
{
    String separator = System.getProperty("line.separator");

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
    String line, results = "";
    while( ( line = reader.readLine() ) != null)
    {
        results += line + separator;
    }
    reader.close();
    return results;
}
```

Which, I'm using today. I hope this can help someone else.

See you soon.

Answer (score 1):

You can create it like this:

```
    try {
        final FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(fileName + extension, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

Next, you can open and edit it using FileInputStream.

The permissions you need to add:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

See that [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239026/how-to-create-a-file-in-android) or read this [tutorial](http://www.anddev.org/working_with_files-t115.html)

Hope it´s useful

Comment: Thank you Gonzalo Solera, I'm searching for the best way to edit it. Thank you.