# Android Java Read and Save data doesnt work

Tags: java, android, eclipse, load, save

Hey I would like to save datas and then I would like to read them and put them in a EditText

```
    speichern.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        save();
        tv.setText("gespeichert");

        }

    });

private  void save() {
    try {
        File myFile = new File("bla.txt");
        myFile.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
        OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = 
                                new    OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
        myOutWriter.append(string.toString() + "\n");
        myOutWriter.append(string2.toString());

        myOutWriter.close();
        fOut.close();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                "Gespeichert",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

> ```
>             private void read() {
>                   int bla;
>                   StringBuffer strInhalt = new StringBuffer("");
>                   try {
>                    FileInputStream in = openFileInput("bla.txt");
> ```

```
                   while( (bla = in.read()) != -1)
                    strInhalt.append((char)bla);

                  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
                  } catch (IOException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
                  }
```

What can i change?`
pelase help me
I'm usin eclipse
And i would like to safe the .txt not external.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? If so, could you provide the stacktrace? :)

Comment: Whhen I press load I get the android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe you are creating your file correctly:

```
File file = new File("test.txt");
file.createNewFile();

if(file.exists())
{
     OutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(file);              
     fo.write("Hello World");
     fo.close();
     System.out.println("file created: "+file);
     url = upload.upload(file);
}
```

And to read this file:

```
 try {
    // open the file for reading
    InputStream instream = openFileInput("test.txt");


// if file the available for reading
if (instream) {
  // prepare the file for reading
  InputStreamReader inputreader = new InputStreamReader(instream);
  BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(inputreader);

  String line;

  // read every line of the file into the line-variable, on line at the time
  while (( line = buffreader.readLine())) {
    // do something with the settings from the file
  }

}

// close the file again      
instream.close();
  } catch (java.io.FileNotFoundException e) {
    // do something if the myfilename.txt does not exits
  }
```

And don't forget to encapsulate code with a `try-catch` block to catch an `IOException` which is thrown from these objects.

**EDIT**

Add this to your manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

or...

```
File filesDir = getFilesDir();
Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(filesDir, filename));
```

Hope that helps! :)

Comment: `private void read() {
    try {
    File myFile = new File("bla.txt");
    FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(myFile);
    BufferedReader myReader = new BufferedReader(
      new InputStreamReader(fIn));
    
    for(int i= 0; i<=1; i++){
     if(i == 0){
      bla = Integer.parseInt(myReader.readLine());
     }
     if(i == 1){
      bla2 = Integer.parseInt(myReader.readLine());
     }
    }
    myReader.close();

   }`

Comment: @user3722368 You are creating a new file right before you read it

Comment: can I send you my full projekt and you fix it?

Comment: @user3722368 I won't be able to do that for you :( Sorry... However this link may be able to help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239026/how-to-create-a-file-in-android

Comment: Oh I restartet the emulator an now I can safe datas:) thank you:)

Comment: private void read() {
    try {
     File filesDir = getFilesDir();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(filesDir, "bla.txt"));
    FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "bla.txt");
    BufferedReader myReader = new BufferedReader(
      new InputStreamReader(fIn));
    
    for(int i= 0; i<=1; i++){
     if(i == 0){
      bla = Integer.parseInt(myReader.readLine());
     }
     if(i == 1){
      bla2 = Integer.parseInt(myReader.readLine());
     }
    }
    myReader.close();
What shold I change there? I don't understand...:(

Comment: ´FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "bla.txt");
    BufferedReader myReader = new BufferedReader(
      new InputStreamReader(fIn));
    
    for(int i= 0; i<=1; i++){
     if(i == 0){
      bla = Integer.parseInt(myReader.readLine());
     }
     if(i == 1){
      bla2 = Integer.parseInt(myReader.readLine());
     }
    }
    myReader.close();` What should I change here?:) my last problem;)

Comment: Try using `openFileInput("myfilename.txt");` to instantiate your new file, instead of creating a new one, like my example :) @user3722368

Comment: where should i do this?

Comment: InputStream instream = openFileInput("bla.txt"); like this?

Comment: Yes! Perfect! @user3722368

Comment: I used the same wihc you hab postet but there was m mistake

Comment: I think the problem then is the location of the file @Strik3r I have edited my example

Comment: what should I change?:)

Comment: Try `File file = new File("test.txt");` **instead** **of** `FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "bla.txt");` also restart emulator again

Comment: hmm is dont change anything:(

Comment: what means instream?!:o

Comment: `instream` is the variable name I gave to `InputStream` @Strik3r

Comment: yes but how could you use them in an if-clause without anything else?:o

Comment: Maybe try the `availble` method, like this -> `instream.available()`, this returns a int but if you go like... `if(instream.available() > 0)`; I'm taking a shot in the dark :P

Comment: hmm but there is always the FileNotFound..:(