# How to add a file automatically when I install my android application on a device?

Tags: java, android

I m developing an application. My application read some config parameters from: `/data/data/package_name/shared_prefs`.

I have to create this file manually each time I install the application on a new deice. How I can make the file created automatically when I install my android application

Comment: [Create a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239026/how-to-create-a-file-in-android), and you can use Shared preference for saving a flag if that's first time run or not. If false, create file and set flag to true, else continue with other code

Comment: u want to create Shared preference file?

Answer (score 0):

In your first Activity(MainActivity) you need to add this code to create Shared Preference file

```
String MY_PREFS_NAME = "FileName"; 
int MODE_PRIVATE = 0; //Zero means private mode
Sting strStore ="some string to store in file"  
int value = 6;//integer value to store in file 
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME,
                                    MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putString("Storestr", strStore);
editor.putInt("intvalue", value);
editor.commit();
```

To get the Shared Preference file value

```
SharedPreferences GetValues = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME , MODE_PRIVATE);  
String strGETSPStore = GetValues.getString("Storestr", "");
int GETSPvalue = GetValues.getInt("intvalue", 0); //Zero is default value
```

The file will store in the path:
`/data/data/package_name/shared_prefs/FileName.xml` , File will be created automatically when app is started.
And Shared preference file is an `.xml` file.
If File already exists it will re-write the file when you start your application again.