# Android Core API: Download/read a file

Tags: android, dropbox

I am using Dropbox Core API to connect my Android application. But i cannot manage to download/read a file from dropbox.

I am using the following code to download and read a file but it doesn't work.

```
  FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
 try {
     File file = new File("/path/to/new/user.txt");
     outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
     mDBApi.getFile("/user.txt", null, outputStream, null);
 } catch (Exception e) {
     System.out.println("Something went wrong: " + e);
 } finally {
     if (outputStream != null) {
         try {
             outputStream.close();
         } catch (IOException e) {}
     }
 }
//This line of code reads the content of the local file that we downloaded
 InputStream instream = new FileInputStream("/path/to/new/usertxt.php");
 InputStreamReader inputreader = new InputStreamReader(instream);
 BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(inputreader);
 mTestOutput.setText(buffreader.readLine());
```

I get the following error

```
Something went wrong: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /path/to/new/user.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Could someone show me a working sample code?

Comment: I think you need to create the file first

Comment: But, doesn't this command do that?  File file = new File("/path/to/new/user.txt"); If not, how should i do it. Please, show me a robust sample if you can.

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239026/how-to-create-a-file-in-android