# java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/sdcard/MyApp/questions.txt: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, save, android-manifest

I have a problem when I try to save a file. First of all, it worked correctly when I try it on an older Eclipse, but I have to use new Eclipse so I export the project from the older Eclipse and import it on the new. Now it doesn't save and give me this excepction:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/sdcard/MyApp/questions.txt: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

I put the code I use to save (this code works on the older eclipse, in the new gives me the exception):

```
public void saveDates(boolean mainScreen)
{

    String extr = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File mFolder = new File(extr + "/MyApp");
    if (!mFolder.exists()) 
    {
        mFolder.mkdir();
    }
    String strF = mFolder.getAbsolutePath();
    File mSubFolder = new File(strF /*+ "/MyApp-SubFolder"*/);
    if (!mSubFolder.exists()) 
    {
        mSubFolder.mkdir();
    }

    //Nombre del fichero
    String s = "questions.txt";

    BufferedWriter out;      
    try 
    {
        FileWriter fileWriter = new  FileWriter(mSubFolder.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + s, false);
        out = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);

        out.write(indexAnswer + ";");
        out.write("\r\n");
        out.write(finished + ";");
        out.write("\r\n");
        out.write(directricesGenerales + ";");
        out.write("\r\n");
        out.write(politicaAmbiental + ";");
        out.write("\r\n");
        out.write(planificacion + ";");
        out.write("\r\n");
        out.write(implementacion + ";");
        out.write("\r\n");
        out.write(verificacion + ";");
        out.write("\r\n");
        out.write(revision + ";");
        out.write("\r\n");
        out.write(definicionProyecto + ";");
        out.write("\r\n");
        out.write(analisisAmbiental + ";");
        out.write("\r\n");
        out.write(desarrollo + ";");
        out.write("\r\n");
        out.write(disenyoDetalle + ";");
        out.write("\r\n");
        out.write(planAccion + ";");
        out.write("\r\n");
        out.write(evaluacionContinua + ";");
        out.write("\r\n");
        out.close();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Datos guardados.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    if(mainScreen)
    {
        // Cerrar la ventana de test y volver a la de inicio
        Intent intent = new Intent();

        intent.setClass(questions.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

And my manifest file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.XXX"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="22" />



<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.ecotoolin.principal"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"> 
        <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>



    <activity
        android:name="com.example.ecotoolin.questions"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"> 
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.ecotoolin.Chart"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"> 
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.ecotoolin.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.ecotoolin.reload"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"> 
    </activity>



    <activity
        android:name="com.example.ecotoolin.sendMail"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"> 
    </activity>
</application>

 <uses-permission 
    android:name="android.permission.INTERNET">
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission 
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" > 
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />    

</manifest>
```

And an image of my emulator details:

[image]

Can anyone help me? Iwant to save the file like I do it in the older version, I don't know why doesn't work.

Comment: does your file actually exist. If not then you first need to create the file before reading it.

Comment: i think i'm creating the file, see the saveDates method, I create the folder, is that what you mean with create the file?

Comment: my mFolder.mkdir() return false, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need this permission in manifest to read files:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`

Second, does your file actually exist. If not then you first need to create the file before writing data to it.

How to create a file: [How to create a file in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239026/how-to-create-a-file-in-android)

Sample code to create a file:

```
// use "File.separator" instead of "/"
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "test.txt");

//create the file
file.createNewFile();

//text you want to write to your file
String text = "your_text";

//check if file exists
if(file.exists()){
    OutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(file);

    //write the data
    fo.write(text);

    //close to avoid memory leaks
    fo.close();

    //give a log message that the file was created with "text"
    System.out.println("file created: "+file);
}
```

Comment: i think i'm creating the file, see the saveDates method, I create the folder, is that what you mean with create the file?

Comment: I review my code and I see that mkdir doesn't do anything, I do: if(mFolder,mkdir()) ----- else ------- and it doesn't enter on the if or on the else, it just go out of that

Comment: my mFolder.mkdir() return false, why?

Comment: Do you have a logcat @Imrik?

Comment: yes: 05-25 05:29:23.830: I/System.out(15638): false
05-25 05:29:23.840: I/System.out(15638): false
05-25 05:29:23.860: W/System.err(15638): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/sdcard/MyApp/questions.txt: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

the false value that put the logcat was my System.out.println(mFolder.mkdir()); output. With System.out.println(mFolder.mkdirs()); it returns false too

Comment: I added a sample code, please try if that works. And have you got read and write permission in your manifest?

Comment: i have this exception "java.io.IOException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)" on "file.CreateNewFile();"

yes, I have read and write permissions

Comment: @Imrik try on other devices, and don't know if this is gonna help but `rebuild` your project