# how to create Crete new file every time when the button presses?

Tags: android, file, storage, audio-recording

I just have only basic knowledge about android. today i developed one audio recording application, but the problem is user can record audio and it can play the audio, when it runs the second time(or user press the record button again) the newly recorded file replaces withe the old file from the storage, i want create new file for each and every recording operations , how to do that ?

**this is my main activity**

```
package com.hackerinside.jaisonjoseph.sample_recorder;

   import android.media.MediaPlayer;
   import android.media.MediaRecorder;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.os.Environment;
   import android.provider.MediaStore;
   import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
   import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
   import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
   import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.view.Menu;
   import android.view.MenuItem;
   import android.widget.Button;
   import android.widget.Toast;

    import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button play,stop,record;
private MediaRecorder myAudioRecorder;
private String outputfile;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    play=(Button)findViewById(R.id.play);
    stop=(Button)findViewById(R.id.stop);
    record=(Button)findViewById(R.id.record);
    stop.setEnabled(false);
    play.setEnabled(false);


    outputfile= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/recording.mp3";


    myAudioRecorder=new MediaRecorder();
    myAudioRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    myAudioRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    myAudioRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
    myAudioRecorder.setOutputFile(outputfile);


 record.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {

         try {

             myAudioRecorder.prepare();
             myAudioRecorder.start();
     }
     catch (IllegalStateException ise){



     }catch (IOException ioe){



         }
            record.setEnabled(false);
            stop.setEnabled(true);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"record startded",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

     }

 });





    stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {



            myAudioRecorder.stop();
            record.setEnabled(true);
            myAudioRecorder.release();
            myAudioRecorder=null;
            stop.setEnabled(false);
            play.setEnabled(true);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"recorded audio",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

    });
            play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                 @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                     MediaPlayer mediaPlayer=new MediaPlayer();

                     try {
                             mediaPlayer.setDataSource(outputfile);
                             mediaPlayer.prepare();
                             mediaPlayer.start();
                             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"playing  audio",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
 // here
    }

}
   });








    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;











}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a file in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239026/how-to-create-a-file-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your record button click use this line

```
outputfile= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/recording_"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".mp3";
```

If you give same file name, the file will be override the old one.

Answer (score 1):

Use Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() to create unique files name for each recording.

```
outputfile=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/recording_"+ Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()+".mp3";
```

Also create one function to create new audio file and initialise recorder with new file reference.

```
private void prepareNewRecording() {
   outputfile=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/recording_"+ Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()+".mp3";
   myAudioRecorder=newMediaRecorder();
   myAudioRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
   myAudioRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
   myAudioRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
   myAudioRecorder.setOutputFile(outputfile);
}
```

Now call above function from start recording

```
prepareNewRecording();
myAudioRecorder.prepare();
myAudioRecorder.start();
```