# How can I see a created file in Device File Explorer?

Tags: android

```
fun saveFile(text: String, filename: String){
    val fos = openFileOutput(filename, MODE_PRIVATE)
    fos.write(text.toByteArray())

    fos.close()
}
```

I made text file using filestream and I want to see file in Device File Explorer. I'm using Galaxy Note3 for debugging.

I knew the created files are saved in \data\data\com.example.package. but There are no files and directories. I checked the file stream works well.

How can I see a created file in Device File Explorer?

I also used adb shell and put "run-as com.example.package" but it show me "Package'com.example.package' is unknown."

Thank you for your help

[This is Device File Explorer image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4TaS.png)

Comment: did you try to use synchronize option?

Comment: show `openFileOutput` method, there is no info where are you trying to store your files, this method is creating `FileOutputStream`, but with which path? due to Scoping Storage introduced some time ago your files should/may be placed in `/Android/data/<package_name>` folder on external storage (which in fact may be built-in, it just not a system partition)

Comment: @snachmsm 
    public FileOutputStream openFileOutput(String name, int mode)
            throws FileNotFoundException {
        return mBase.openFileOutput(name, mode);
    } // this is override method in FileOutputStream. I didn't set storing path. The book studying now tell me internal storage set default directory \data\data\package\file

Comment: @HasnatHasan I already use synchronize after every build

Comment: if there is no file then you should have some exception in log, post it. are you even creating this file before streaming data to it? this may be mandatory... [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239026/how-to-create-a-file-in-android) you have nice answers similar to your case